# undefined columns error when trying to subset

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

```
subset_car_data <- car_data[car_data, car_data$Car_Type == "N" & car_data$Term == 60 & car_data$FICO>=675 & car_data$FICO<=725 & car_data$Amount>=30000 & car_data$Amount<=40000]
```

this is my code. I am attempting to create a subset subset_car_data from car_data with specific conditions. However, I keep getting the error: [image]

Comment: I think what you need is `car_data[car_data$Car_Type == "N" & car_data$Term == 60 & car_data$FICO>=675 & car_data$FICO<=725 & car_data$Amount>=30000 & car_data$Amount<=40000, ]` Or `subset(car_data, Car_Type == "N" & Term == 60 & FICO>=675 & FICO<=725 & Amount>=30000 & Amount<=40000)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  0   1
2   0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0   0
3   0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0   0
4   0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   0
5   0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0   0
6   1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  1   0
7   1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1   0
8   0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0   1
9   0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1   1
10  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1   1
```

You should do something like:

```
subset_df <- df[df$X1 == 1 & df$X2 == 1 & df$X3 == 1,]
subset_df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
8   1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   0
10  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  0   1
```

Instead of:

```
subset_df <- df[df,df$X1 == 1 & df$X2 == 1 & df$X3 == 1]
```